# Navigate within webview on listview click in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

I have a webview in my Android app which loads a large HTML file.I also have a list view which consists of an index of all the headings involved in the HTML file.Now I want that if user presses a list item in listview(index) then he/she can move to that party of the HTML file...
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You'll make `js` for that and load it on your `HTML` page.

Comment: @SimplePlan could you please elaborate